# Expected value and variance of expected value for a poisson process

Tags: poisson-distribution

The number of arrivals at a customer information desk is 2 per minute. Assuming the number of arrivals follows a poisson distribution, find (a) the expected number of arrivals in 3 minutes and  (b) the variance of the number of enquiries arriving in 3 minutes.

**Attempt:**

(a)
\begin{equation}
 E(x=2) = 2 \times 3 = 6
\end{equation}
is this correct for part (a)?

I am not sure how to start with part (b) - any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes your first attempt is correct. As for the variance, you should have a formula for that in terms of the mean arrivals (typically denoted $\mu$ or $\lambda$, check the formulas that you've been taught).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. In any reference to the variance, that I have found, it says that the variance and expected value both = $\mu$?

Comment: That's correct, so what will be your answer?

Comment: Both the variance and the expected value = 6?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @BillWallis We did this because expected value and variance are equal in poisson, right?

Comment: @user585380 Absolutely.

Comment: @BillWallis thank you so much.